# How to execute SublimeText commands from windows CMD?

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How to execute SublimeText commands from a Windows command prompt?

**More Explanation:**
I can execute SublimeText commands from the SublimeText console.
***Examples:*** (from SublimeText console)
`view.run_command("copy_path")`
`window.run_command("open_dir", {"dir": "$file_path", "file": "$file_name"})`
`window.run_command("prev_view_in_stack")`
What I'm looking for, is to execute SublimeText commands from a Windows command prompt.

Comment: It's unclear from the way you asked, but presuming that you meant that you want to execute Sublime commands from a windows command prompt, you probably want `sublime_text --command`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, could you please add this as an answer so that I can choose it as the answer of the question.

Comment: @OdatNurd I edited the question to be more clear. Kindly add your answer please in order to select as the answer for the question. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have it covered (I just got back into the office and saw your request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sublime_text --command "your command"`.

Credits to [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd) for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456463/how-to-execute-sublimetext-commands-via-windows-cmd#comment83905773_48456463)

**Examples:**
`sublime_text --command "copy_path"`
`sublime_text --command "open_dir {""dir"": ""$file_path"", ""file"": ""$file_name""}"`
`sublime_text --command "prev_view_in_stack"`